# Insert the primary key of a table into foreign key of another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Say I have two tables, 'users' and 'restaurants'.

Users Table:

| user_id | email | u_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a@b.com | John |
| 2 | c@d.com | Jane |

Restaurants table –
here `owner` is the foreign key referencing `user_id`

| restaurant_id | r_name | address | owner |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | KFC | New York | 1 |
| 2 | Starbucks | Texas | 2 |

i have a form where the user enter details into the first table. And then i have another form to enter details into second table. how do i set the values in 'owner' column? The user_id and restaurant_id are auto generated. How do i know which restaurant belongs to which user?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SELECT statement in your INSERT, like this:

```
INSERT INTO restaurants(c1, c2, c3) 
SELECT 'foo' -- new content 
, 'bar' -- new content 
, id_user -- primary key used for the FK constraint 
FROM users 
WHERE username = 'Mickey';
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second form(form to enter details into second table),
a dropdown can be provided which displays list of users from table 1. dropdown usually has value and text part. value can be set to user_id and text can be set to  u_name / email.
r_name and address, you are getting from user in the second form?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).